# How does restangular talk to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, grails, restangular

I am total JS newbie working on a project build in Grail 2.4.4, a web-app. It's a working app, build by a developer whom is not available anymore.

To get it to work locally I had to upgrade it to Grails 3.2.0. I got it almost working in Netbeans. But I got stuck at getting the data from the MySQL database. 
The Chrome inspector says:
`angular.min.js GET http://localhost:8080/<app>/currency/allCurrencies 404 ()`
The controllers are written in Restangular which call the above URL.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Restangular is an Angular library which simplifies and standardizes making calls to a REST backend (which in your case is a Grails app). So, Restangular does not directly retrieve data from your a database, it invokes a web service which (in some cases) may retrieve data from a database.

In your case, Restangular is attempting to retrieve data from the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/<app>/currency/allCurrencies` but you are getting a 404 response, indicating that there is no endpoint mapped to this URL.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP REST** helps you connect to the API easily. Restangular can handle that by sending standard methods [Get, Post, Delete, Put] to the api like what you see.

> This mean StudentController > Get()

```
localhost:2045/api/student
```

> This mean StudentController > Get(Guid id)

```
localhost:2045/api/student/8ae37cfa-905b-4c71-ad03-bf416d93bdf8
```

> This mean StudentController > POST(Guid id) ... if you send Post method to the API, it will detect it, this work also on put method

```
localhost:2045/api/student
```

> use this module to get easily rest api.

[Http-Rest-Service](https://github.com/maherAshori/Http-Rest-Service)